# Response.Redirect Doesn't Work in my Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#

My page does not redirect to the Page I have specified. While I am doing so it says `The name "Response" does not exist in the current context`
Please also help me with getting the register value in the database while doing the signup.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LoginSystem123
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=mukesh-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial       Catalog=testDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            var myCommand = new SqlCommand();

            var cmd = "SELECT * FROM [User] Where [User].Email =" + "'" + textBoxEmail.Text + "'";
            myCommand.CommandText = cmd;
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

            myConnection.Open();

            var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            bool isRegisteredUser = myReader.Read();
            if (isRegisteredUser)
            {
                var PasswordFromDatabase = myReader.GetString(5);

                if (textBoxPassword.Text == PasswordFromDatabase.TrimEnd())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged on !");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid password. Try again");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid user");

            }
        }

        /* private void buttonSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SignUp.cs");
        }
        */
        private void buttonSignUp_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SignUp.cs");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW have you ever heard of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? You **ALWAYS** need to encode any strings entered by the user before inserted into a `sql` command.

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Redirect` is used to redirect to another page in an ASP website - nothing like this works in Windows Forms.

If `SignUp.cs` defines a `Form`, you can do something like this to show it:

```
var signup = new SignUp();
signup.ShowDialog();
```

If you let us know more about what you're trying to do, we can probably be a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect only works for web applications, and it looks like you're coding for Windows  application.

You should do this instead:

```
SignUp su = new SignUp();
su.Show();
this.Hide();
```